# Win 8.1 guest on VirtualBox 5 running on Wayland 1.8 freezes after login

Tags: windows, virtualbox, gnome3, wayland

I'm testing GNOME 3.16.3 wayland (1.8) session on ArchLinux 64bit. Everything seems to work fine so far except for VirtualBox 5.0.2.
If I run windows 8.1 as guest, after entering the password on the login screen, VirtualBox just freezes (that not happens while running on X11).
Also, I have the following env set:

```
GDK_BACKEND=wayland
CLUTTER_BACKEND=wayland
```

Anyone had similar issues? Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found out that by disabling hardware acceleration (both 3D and 2D video) on my virtual machine settings does the trick.
Perhaps not the best solution but I can live with that for now...